# Distance from the midpoint of a radius to another point on the same radius

Tags: geometry, circles

Here is a picture of the problem. Note that $M$ is the midpoint of $OB$. How do I figure out what $MH$ is?

[image]

Comment: A ruler?  Exactly which values are you given to work with?

Answer (score 3):

Since your other questions indicate that you've worked with hyperbolic geometry, you probably are (or probably should become) familiar with the ["Power of a Point"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) with respect to a circle. For point $M$ in your circle, this allows us to write

$$|AM||MB| = |CM||MN|$$

By similar triangles $\triangle OMC \sim \triangle HMN$,

$$\frac{|MH|}{|NM|} = \frac{|MO|}{|CM|}$$

From here, it's just some simple algebra.

Comment: Cool. I thought there might be a more geometric (less algebraic) solution. I vaguely recall the "power of a point" thing from high school, but that was 50 years ago, so the memory is pretty foggy.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that the circle has radius = 1. If this is not the case, we can scale the answer later.

So, the circle has equation $x^2+y^2 = 1$.

The line CN has equation $y=1-2x$. The point N is the intersection of this line with the circle, so it's $x$-coordinate satisfies the equation $x^2 + (1-2x)^2 = 1$. Solve this equation to get the $x$-coordinate of N. The solution is actually $x = 0.8$. Then MH is $0.8 - 0.5$, which is $0.3$.

By using a ruler, as suggested in the comment above, you can check that this is roughly correct :-)